# Padding on CSS grid container isn't rendering on the right side

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm new to CSS Grid and can't figure out why the padding on the container isn't rendering when there is overflow scrolling.

This is the HTML I've got setup:

```
<div class="Container">
    <div class="Column"></div>
    <div class="Column"></div>
    <div class="Column"></div>
    <div class="Column"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS(SCSS) is:

```
$unit: 8px;

.Container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, $unit * 47); // 8px * 47 = 376px
  grid-column-gap: $unit * 4; // 8px * 4 = 32px
  padding: 2 * $unit;
}

.Column {
  background: green;
  height: 100px;
}
```

There will be overflow depending on the width of the viewport but this is a desired result. My problem is to the right of the `.Container` the padding that was added doesn't render. It'll render to the top, bottom and left of the container but not on the right side.

Here is a CodePen to illustrate the issue:

https://codepen.io/michaellee/pen/BYvowX